# clarification with argparse in python 3.2 please

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

hello im new to python and have been reading over the documentation and am having trouble with argparse

here is the code i am trying it onsimple explanation for a simple minded person please
thanks in advance

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import argparse
from string import ascii_lowercase
from string import ascii_uppercase
from string import digits
from string import punctuation

def options():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Create a list of characters")
    parser.add_argument('-c:')
    if (args.c):# == "-c:":
        if "-c" + ":" + "caps":
            charset = ascii_uppercase
        elif "-c:" + "small":
            charset = ascii_lowercase
        elif "-c:" + "digits":
            charset = digits
        elif "-c:" + "punc":
            charset = punctuation + " "
        elif "-c:" + "space":
            charset = " "
        elif "-c:" + "all":
            charset = ascii_lowercase + ascii_uppercase + digits + punctuation + space
        else:
            print("when using -c you must include an option! (caps, small, digits, punc, space, all)")

def filename():
    filename = open('C:\\Users\\MSec\\Desktop\\WordLists\\'+sys.argv[1], 'w')
    return 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename()
    options()
```

again im new  didnt quite understand the documentation

i guess while im at it  is there a better ( or more pythonic) way to code all the options instead of many elif statements?

thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your if statements are always true.

```
if "-c" + ":" + "caps":
```

Means

```
if "-c:caps":
```

The string "-c:caps" is non-false. The same goes for the rest of the similar if-statements.

You probably mean

```
if args.c == 'caps':
```

And no, there is often no better way that a long list of elifs. There are other ways, but this is the easiest to write and understand, and hence the best.

In this case, however, you can make a dictionary:

```
CHAR_OPTIONS = {'caps': ascii_uppercase,
                'small': ascii_lowercase,
                etc....
               }
```

And use it like so:

```
charset = CHAR_OPTIONS[args.c]
```

Comment: thanks that makes sense however now it returns a global name args not defined but if its being used in def options the way it is dosent that make it a local variable?

Comment: @learn_What: No, it doesn't return that "now". Your example also did that, I assumed you just made an error when copying it in. Your example forgets to actually call parser.parse(). What you need to do is stop writing a lot of code that doesn't work and then try to make it work. Instead write only a little bit of code at a time, and make that little bit of code work, and then extend it. So at this point, you should start over, and write like one, two or three lines of code at a time, and make sure these lines work, then add more lines bit by bit. Then ask questions of you have problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if this was what you were looking for, but you can always capitalize strings using `.upper()`, and lowercase strings with `.lower()`. :)

Comment: That's not at all the point of the question... The `c` argument defines a list of characters. Some options are lower or upper letters